# vectorized interpolation on array with nans

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate an image cube NDIM=(dim_frequ, dim_spaxel1, dim_spaxel1) along the frequency axis. The aim is to oversample the frequency space. The array may contain nans. It would, of course, be possible to run two for loops over the array but that's definitely too slow.

What I want in pseudo code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
dim_frequ, dim_spaxel1, dim_spaxel2 = 2559, 70, 70
cube       =  np.random.rand(dim_frequ, dim_spaxel1, dim_spaxel2)
cube.ravel()[np.random.choice(cube.size, 1000, replace=False)] = np.nan 

wavelength =  np.arange(1.31, 2.5894999999, 5e-4) # deltaf so that len(wavelength)==DIMfrequ
wavelength_over = np.arange(1.31, 2.5894999999, 5e-5)
cube_over  = interp1d(wavelength, cube, axis=0, kind='quadratic', fill_value="extrapolate")(wavelength_over)
cube_over[np.isnan(cube_over)] # array([], dtype=float64)
```

- I've tried `np.interp` which can only handle 1D data (?)
- I've tried `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` which can in principle handle
  arrays along a given axis, but returns nans (I assume because of the
  nans in the array)

  - This actually works in the case the kind is = 'linear'. I'd actually like it a bit fancier though, as soon as I set kind to 'quadratic' it returns nans.
- I've tried the `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`
  which raises a `ValueError` again because of the nans.

Any ideas what else to try? I am quite free in terms of the type of the interpolation, but it shouldn't be *too fancy*, i.e. nothing crazier than a spline or a low order polynomial

Comment: Can you provide a fully working small piece of code please? I am not 100% sure what is going on since you have no input data shown.

Comment: [scipy's Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf) works find with high dimensional data. Also [LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator)

Comment: @ak_slick example now includes a MWE that will reproduce the [nan, ..., nan] in the case of scipy.interpolate's interp1d....

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things.

**First**

This returns all nan because cube_over has no nan in it after the above

```
cube_over[np.isnan(cube_over)]
```

Since `np.isnan(cube_over)` is all False

Otherwise it appears to be interpolating everything in the `wavelength_over` array.

**Second**

[scipy doesn't like nans (see the docs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)  Typical practice is to drop the nan's from your set of points to interpolate since it typically will not add any value to the interpolation function.

Although it appears to be working with you interp1d example above. I am guessing it is dropped them along the axis when it builds the interpolation function, but I am not sure.

**Third**

What value do you actually want to interpolate? I am not sure what your desired output / endpoint is. It appears that your code is working more or less as expected. When you are interpolating you `wavelength_over` array.  Seeing as they are so similar (if not the same value as the `wavelength` array.  I think you might benefit from a 2d interpolation method but again I do not have a good understanding of your goal.

See [2d interpolation options in scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)

Hope this helps.